# XML dynamic content to extract in C# object

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have a xml source with dynamic content

```
<content base="path">
<folder name="Test_dossier1">
    <folder name="Test_dossier2">
        <folder name="Test_dossier3">
            <file name="test_fichier3.txt"/>
        </folder>
    <file name="test_fichier2.txt"/>
</folder>
<file name="test_fichier1.txt"/>
</folder>
<file name="adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd"/>
<file name="base64.js"/>
<file name="eniscormres.htm"/>
<file name="functions.js"/>
<file name="imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd"/>
<file name="imsmanifest.xml"/>
</content>
```

So the folder node is dynamic. This can have X folders and files nodes children.
How can Parse this dynamic node?

This is my xml parse code for extract File nodes :

```
var files = content.SelectNodes ("file");
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode element in files) {
            var file = new OfflineGetCourseContentFile {
                Id = q.Id,
                File = element.Attributes.GetNamedItem ("name").Value
            };
            InsertSqliteDb.InsertIntoDB (file);
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What problem are you facing with the C# code you posted?

Comment: Usually in this case you would use recursion - create a function that takes a folder node. Within that function you process its child nodes - for each folder node, you call the same function again.

Comment: C.Evenhuis, do you have an example? I don't know exactly how to do!

Comment: Siva Gopal, my code works perfectly, I would like to know how get dynamically the value from folder node. Because this node can have n children nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain what you want achieve using Linq to XML, `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`, since **xml.Descendants("file")**  will return EVERY *file* node in the document, you have just do to something like this:

```
// since st is an XMLDocument
var xml = XDocument.Parse(st.OuterXml);
    foreach (foreach (var file in xml.Descendants("file"))) 
    {
        var file = new OfflineGetCourseContentFile {
            Id = q.Id,
            File = file.Value
        };
        InsertSqliteDb.InsertIntoDB (file);
    }
```

**XContainer.Descendants Method (XName)**

> Returns a filtered collection of the descendant elements for this
>   document or element, in document order. Only elements that have a
>   matching XName are included in the collection.
>
> Return Value Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable An
>   IEnumerable of XElement containing the descendant elements of the
>   XContainer that match the specified XName.

Comment: My xml is a file from server. SO I use HttpClient to get the xml. And return me a XMLDocument. I can't use your solution, I do?

Comment: you can simply parse it : XDocument.Parse(doc.OuterXml) where doc is XMLDocument

Comment: So with XDocument.Parse how can get the item name for each folder's node? et their children nodes? Because the folder's node can have a file and/or another folder's node ...

Comment: using XDocument parse you will obtain EVERY node by name, child and not, please read my edited answer

Comment: Thanks InvernoMuto, This is my solution I found with your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks InvernoMuto, This is my solution I found with your help

```
var inner = content.OuterXml;
        var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(inner);
        foreach (var fds in xml.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()) {
            Console.WriteLine (fds.Name.LocalName);
            if(fds.Name.LocalName != "content")
                Console.WriteLine ("Name {0}, Parent {1}", fds.Attribute("name").Value, fds.Parent.Attribute("name"));
        }
```

Thanks for you help guys